# How do I know if the software on a computer is compatible with Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, drivers, windows-10-upgrade, compatibility

Several computers at home currently run on Windows 7 or Windows 8.

How do I know if the software on those computers is compatible with Windows 10 ? When I say software, I mean:

- Drivers for the computer components
- Drivers or software for accessories (printers, for example)
- Drivers or software for miscellaneous devices (mobile phones, sat nav, etc.)
- Miscellaneous software applications

From what I have seen, Microsoft's **Get Windows 10** upgrade tool has a **Check your PC** functionality. It checks that your computer is compatible, and also gives you warnings if some apps are known to be incompatible. If there is no warning about a given app, it *should* work fine (I am a bit concerned about the *should* part).

Comment: Microsoft can't tell if some specific devices or applications stop working after you upgrade your PC, because their database of tested devices and applications is limited. To be sure, install Windows 10 in a virtual machine and test all devices and applications there. If you have tested everything you need, simply upgrade your PC.

Comment: It does work fine in nearly all cases, but *there is no guarantee*. Note that you can upgrade, and if you have any issues, you can go back to the old version, relatively easily. Millions of people have successfully done it, so if you don't have some really exotic software/hardware, you should be good.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Drivers are normally specifically do or do not support Windows 10.

Comment: Other than your tool,,go to the software publishers website and see what they've said.

Comment: @Ramhound **The context** is: we have at home different pc configurations; in terms of OS (several Win 7's, a Win 8.1) and in terms of software (software for their mobile phones, printers, cameras, sat navs, etc.). **The problem is**: I need to know if drivers or apps can have issues (and then I will have to see what to do: delay the WIn 10 upgrade or look for a replacement app when possible, for example). **Questions that come to mind are**: is the "Check your PC" exhaustive ? Are there alternatives i.e. listings of applications win10 compatibilities ?

Comment: Microsoft only will uninstall an application they have tested and know is not compatible with Windows 10.

Comment: @GiantTree I think I will try to create test VMs but there can be apps that work fine with a clean Win 10 installation, but will have issues when upgrading from a previous WIndows version. Or [other surprises](http://www.ghacks.net/2015/11/24/beware-latest-windows-10-update-may-remove-programs-automatically/) :D

Comment: @salcoin - So a program is removed.  Just install it again.  " Are there alternatives i.e. listings of applications win10 compatibilities ?" Microsoft does not publish a list, software vendors are expected to provided this information, Microsoft is only removing applications known to them to cause problems or prevent the upgrade from being successful.

Comment: I always recommend a clean installation, but most people I know had no problem upgrading whatsoever, so I think it comes down to the individual setup. Simply reinstall any missing applications and you are good to go.

Comment: @GiantTree and Ramhound: The steps I will follow will be: 1. Creating a new VM and test out apps that could be problematic 2. Back up the current PCs and make clean installations (one PC at a time) so as to test out the drivers for the hardware and accessories 3. Proceed with installing the rest of the apps if 1 and 2 went fine. Edit: Thanks all by the way. It should hopefully go well. It will take some time though :D

Comment: @salcoin exactly what I did a few months ago :)

Comment: Windows 10 upgrade icon has a compatibility checker you can use before upgrading to W10. http://www.zdnet.com/article/will-your-pc-run-windows-10-use-this-well-hidden-compatibility-checker-to-find-out/

Comment: I know, I wrote it in bold in my question :D